# playing youtube video using videojs

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I am trying to play a video using videosjs and added a pluging from:
https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/tree/master/src

My video element:

```
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="150" height="100" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUg-BZAR5ro" }'></video>
```

I get the following error:

> VIDEOJS: 
>   TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'play' of undefined"}
>    video.js:23
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

How do I solve it?

Comment: Are you using requireJS or browserify?

Comment: Yes I did, I used video.js and another framework called youtube.js with the following code:

Comment: <video width="640" height="480" id="MyVideo" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls></video>
            <script src="lib/vjs.youtube.js"></script>
            <script>
                videojs('MyVideo', { "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxDVNuUJavI" }).ready(function() {
                });
                player.on('mouseout', function(){
                    controlBar.addClass('vjs-fade-out');
                });
                player.on('mouseover', function(){
                controlBar.removeClass('vjs-fade-out');
                }); </script>